# Uglify JavaScript code with Sprockets

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sprockets

My project was builded in Rails 2 and was upgraded to Rails 3.1, so I'm having troubles with the assets pipeline configuration, such as precompile.

I'm using app/assets/aplication.js like:

```
//= require jquery 
//= require jquery_ujs
```

My application.rb is:

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

My Gemfile contains uglifier gem:

```
gem 'uglifier'
```

After that I performed:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

and the result code from public/assets/application.js isn't uglified, but when I put this configuration on application.rb:

```
config.assets.compress = true
```

the file is uglified.

Isn't the config.assets.compress configuration used for live compilation? Why does my precompile rake only uglify with this option enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compressing is uglifying. If you don't have that option, then compressing/uglifying doesn't happen. If you want uglifying to happen, enable that option.

Comment: Oh... Now I see... the compress config made the job. That's because in my Rails 3.1 upgraded compress is not set true by default. Thank you!